# android code on how to have different layouts

Tags: java, android

android code on how to make my program go to a different layout each time a button is clicked, like a reminder layout wen you click at a particular date on a custom calendar

```
public void calenderevent(Calendar begintime, Calendar endtime) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", begintime.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
    intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
    intent.putExtra("endTime", endtime.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
    intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

this code does not work

Comment: was that layout predefined ?

Comment: yes layout is predefined n i have a custom calendar, i wanna use a database to store info for every date i click on the calendar, i want a layout to pop up for each date clicked

Answer (score 0):

If Your layout design is predefined,

if you want to change layout on load every time ,
     use random select of Layout and then set that in setcontentView("Layout Id") in on
     create method.
If you want to change it on some event performed,

```
 Call setContentView("Layout Id") method in listener .
```

Comment: i want to call this layout each time i click on a date on the calendar, it goes within a loop, the event has to knw which date iv clicked n provide a layout, how do i go about it??

Comment: also i have to have a database to store the reminder for that particular date, m new to both android n java so its kinda confusing

Comment: when i do manage to make a layout pop up to add my reminder the emulator displays a message saying my calendar is not visible n i need to add an acount

Comment: If you want specific layout on every time you click on date, check with date on which it has been clicked and accordingly display layout.

Comment: Also you can save what layout you have used to which date and can call the layout accordingly